# Python: POST multiple multipart-encoded files

Tags: python, python-requests

As described here, it is possible to send multiple files with one request:
[Uploading multiple files in a single request using python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179345/uploading-multiple-files-in-a-single-request-using-python-requests-module)

However, I have a problem generating these multiple filehandlers from a list.
So let's say I want to make a request like this:

```
sendfiles = {'file1': open('file1.txt', 'rb'), 'file2': open('file2.txt', 'rb')}
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files=sendfiles)
```

How can I generate *sendfiles* from the list *myfiles*?

```
myfiles = ["file1.txt", "file20.txt", "file50.txt", "file100.txt", ...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary comprehension, using [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to remove those extensions from the filenames:

```
import os.path

sendfiles = {os.path.splitext(fname)[0]: open(fname, 'rb') for fname in myfiles}
```

Note that a list of 2-item tuples will do too:

```
sendfiles = [(os.path.splitext(fname)[0], open(fname, 'rb')) for fname in myfiles]
```

Beware; using the `files` parameter to send a multipart-encoded POST *will* read all those files into memory first. Use the [`requests-toolbelt` project](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to build a streaming POST body instead:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import os.path

m = MultipartEncoder(fields={
    os.path.splitext(fname)[0]: open(fname, 'rb') for fname in myfiles})
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=m,
                  headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

Comment: apparently there is a little something in the format of the dict: in the question the filenames don't have their extensions, for some reason.