# send multiple files in a post request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to send multiple files in a post request. Following is the code I use.

```
orig_src = "./orig_src/"
url = "http://"+server+":"+port+"/my_service"
files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(orig_src):
    for fileName in files:
        if len(files) > 0:
            relDir = os.path.relpath(root, orig_src)
            relFile = os.path.join(relDir, fileName)
            files.append(('srcFile', (fileName, open(orig_src+relFile, 'rb'))))
response = requests.post(url, files = files)
```

I get the following error when I try to do this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 66, in join
if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Any idea where the error might be? earlier I created a curl request using -F option and ran it using os.system command. That was running fine. But I  am not able to send the post request now. where am i going wrong?

Comment: Somehow you are passing a `tuple` where you should be passing a `string`.

Comment: yes, but I am not sure where. I took cues from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179345/uploading-multiple-files-in-a-single-request-using-python-requests-module to upload multiple files in single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a tuple to `os.path.join` as the traceback explains (`in join`).

You need a better name for the list that you're passing to requests because you are reusing the name `files` after you declare it as an empty list.

- First you define `files` as an empty list in line 3
- Then you define `files` as the third item you receive from the tuple you're unpacking in your for loop on line 4.

Since you're modifying `files` in place, you're adding tuples to the list. Python expects that you understand this and eventually iterates through the list until it reaches the first tuple. In this case `fileName` is now a tuple and you pass that to `os.path.join` which expects a string, not a tuple.

Change one of the two bindings and you should be fine.