# How to send multiple files using rest_framework.test.APITestCase

Tags: python, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send a couple of files to my backend:

```
class AccountsImporterTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test(self):
        data = [open('accounts/importer/accounts.csv'), open('accounts/importer/apartments.csv')]
        response = self.client.post('/api/v1/accounts/import/', data, format='multipart')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/conjuntos/accounts/tests/cases.py", line 128, in test
    response = self.client.post('/api/v1/accounts/import/', data, format='multipart')
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 168, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 89, in post
    data, content_type = self._encode_data(data, format, content_type)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 64, in _encode_data
    ret = renderer.render(data)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 757, in render
    return encode_multipart(self.BOUNDARY, data)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 156, in encode_multipart
    for (key, value) in data.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I know I'm not preparing the data correctly but is it possible to do it?, how?. Thanks!

**Update:** Trying @Kevin Brown solution

```
def test(self):
    data = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
    data.setlist('files', [open('accounts/importer/accounts.csv'), open('accounts/importer/apartments.csv')])
    response = self.client.post('/api/v1/accounts/import/', data, format='multipart')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Got the following:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/conjuntos/accounts/tests/cases.py", line 130, in test
    response = self.client.post('/api/v1/accounts/import/', data, format='multipart')
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 168, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 89, in post
    data, content_type = self._encode_data(data, format, content_type)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 64, in _encode_data
    ret = renderer.render(data)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 757, in render
    return encode_multipart(self.BOUNDARY, data)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 182, in encode_multipart
    return b'\r\n'.join(lines)
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buffer interface, str found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a list of files to the view, but you aren't sending them correctly. When you send data to a view, whether it is a Django view or DRF view, you are supposed to send it as a list of key-value pairs.

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "file": open("/path/to/file", "rb"),
}
```

To answer your question...

> is it possible to do it?

It does not appear to be possible to upload multiple files using the same key *(in tests)*, but it is possible to spread them out across multiple keys to achieve the same goal. Alternatively, you could set up your views to only handle a single file, and have multiple tests covering different test cases (`apartments.csv`, `accounts.csv`, etc.).

Your exception is being triggered because you are passing a single list instead of a dictionary, and Django cannot parse them correctly.

You *might have some luck* by directly forming the request dictionary [using a `QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) which is the internal representation of form data used by Django.

```
data = QueryDict(mutable=True)
data.setlist("files", [
  open('accounts/importer/accounts.csv', 'rb'),
  open('accounts/importer/apartments.csv', 'rb')
])
```

As this would more closely represent the data sent in through the browser. This has not been tested, but it's the way to send multiple non-file-values in one key.

Comment: @chachan Try reading the files in as binary, see my updated answer.

Comment: that worked!, I have to `str(content)` in the backend but I'm fine with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solves your problem as from the errors its clearly says that the data should not be a **list**

```
data = {"account_csv": open('accounts/importer/accounts.csv'), "apartments_csv": open('accounts/importer/apartments.csv')}
```

This link you might find useful [Uploading multiple files in a single request using python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179345/uploading-multiple-files-in-a-single-request-using-python-requests-module)

Comment: Great guess, but your answer is skirting around the actual issue: Any data sent using form data must be a set of key-value pairs.

Comment: Agree @Kevin. just trying to give OP some sort of hints to get out of this issue.

Comment: Sorry @MaNKuR, tried that too but I got something like `TypeError: sequence item 4: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buffer interface, str found`