# How can i send two image in one python post request

Tags: python, request

This is the api

edited

what I have to do I have to send two images with the key "bank_statement" otherwise the API will send the message "Exactly two images must be submitted." What I am doing with the request is

```
> myfiles = {'bank_statement': open("DOC1.jpg", 'rb'),
>                'bank_statement': open("DOC1.jpg", 'rb')}

is_extractable = requests.post(Validate, files=myfiles)
```

But the response is

> {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 10:00:43.354058', 'message': 'Exactly two
> images must be submitted.', 'error': 'Bad Request', 'status': 400}

I can't figure out where is the problem is.

Comment: What I see is that you send in your Python code "DOC1.jpg" twice...

Comment: I can send same image. It's not the problem @Prins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your dictionary is not consisting of two entries, but only one.

```py
myfiles = {'bank_statement': 'blabla', 'bank_statement': 'blablabla'}
myfiles
```

gives as output

```
{'bank_statement': 'blablabla'}
```

You might have to add it twice, or add a list, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20769921/8601807).

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes that was the case and I have modified the code into this ``` file_list = [
        ('bank_statement', ('image1.jpg', open(image1, 'rb'), 'image/png')),
        ('bank_statement', ('image2.jpg', open(image2, 'rb'), 'image/png'))
    ]```
it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send two images with the one and same parameter you have create a list

```
 file_list = [
        ('bank_statement', ('image1.jpg', open(image1, 'rb'), 'image/png')),
        ('bank_statement', ('image2.jpg', open(image2, 'rb'), 'image/png'))
    ]
```

Here bank_statement is parameter and image1 on open closure is path of files I have sent.